# Can I run a bash script from a file in a separate docker volume before a container starts?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I have a situation where i need to `source` a bash environment file that lives in a separate volume (pulled in via `volumes_from` in `docker-compose`) when a container starts so that all future commands run on the container will execute under that bash environment (it runs some scripts and sets a lot of dynamic variables pulled in from other places).  The reason I'm using a volume instead of just adding this command directly to the image is because the environment file I need to include is outside the Dockerfile context, and Dockerfiles don't support that.

I tried adding a `source /path/to/volume/envfile` line in to the root user's `.bashrc` file in the hopes that it would be run when the container started, but that didn't work. I'm assuming that's because the volumes aren't actually mounted until after the container / shell has started and `.bashrc` commands have already run (which makes sense).

Does anyone have any idea on how I can accomplish something like this?  I'm open to alternative methods, however the one thing I can't change here is moving the file I need inside of the Docker context, as that would break quite a number of other things.

My (slightly edited) Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files: https://gist.github.com/joeellis/235d90799eb647ab00ec

EDIT:  And as a test, I'm trying to run a `rake db:create:all` on the container, like `docker-compose run app rake db:create:all` which is returning an error that the environment file I need cannot be found / loaded.  Interestingly enough, if I shell into the container and run the command, it all seems to work just great.  So maybe when a container is given a command via `run`, it doesn't necessarily open up a shell, but uses something else?

Comment: Works fine for me. What is your base image and run commands?

Comment: @ISanych Ah, well good to know I'm on the right track if it works for you.  Edited post with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the shell within which your `/src/app/bin/start-app` is ran is not an interactive shell => `.bashrc` is not read!

You can fix this by doing this:
Add the env file to instead:
/root/.profile

```
RUN echo "source /src/puppet/path/to/file/env/bootstrap" >> /root/.profile
```

And also run your command as login shell via (sh is bash anyhow for you via the hack in the Dockerfile :) ):

```
command: "sh -lc '/src/app/bin/start-app'"
```

as the command. This should work fine :)
The problem really is just missing to source that file because you're running in a non-interactive shell when running via the docker command instruction.
It works when you shell into the container, because bam you got an interactive shell that sources that file :)

Comment: This definitely was the case.  I wanted to use bash, so I ended up using `bash --login -c '/src/app/bin/start-app'` to the same effect - worked great.  Thanks so much for the help!